# Getting element id from anchor tags and replace href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, joomla

I have a Joomla project, and I have slight problem changing the links in the dropdown menu list.

I have this menu and its child menu.

Shop
- firstcat
- secondcat
- thirdcat

HTML:

```
<ul class="level2">
    <li>
        <a id="firstcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop/firstcat">First Cat</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="secondcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop/secondcat">Second Cat</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="thirdcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop/thirdcat">Third Cat</a>
    </li>
</ul>`
```

Default in Joomla that the menu items are linked to their category_alias. But I want to link the menus to their category_id. Now, I want to get their different id(s) and find their corresponding category_ids in the database and replace the `href` in to their category_id.

Like this:

```
<a id="firstcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop?16">FirstCat</a> 
<a id="secondcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop?17">SecondCat</a>
<a id="thirdcat" href="/my_website/index.php/shop?18">ThirdCat</a>
```

I just wanna do it through JavaScript or jQuery, because it takes time to dig files in Joomla and replace the alias into id.

For now, I only do it manually.
`$('ul.level2 li a#firstcat').attr('href','/my_website/index.php/shop?catid=16');`
`$('ul.level2 li a#secondcat').attr('href','/my_website/index.php/shop?catid=17');`
`$('ul.level2 li a#thirdcat').attr('href','/my_website/index.php/shop?catid=18');`

In php part that I have to get their category_id is this.
`<?php

        echo $menuItem->alias . '<br/>';

        $db = & JFactory::getDBO();

        $db->setQuery('SELECT id FROM #__k2_categories WHERE alias="' . $menuItem->alias . '"');

        $result = $db->loadResult();

        echo $result;

        foreach ($result as $res) {

            echo $res->id;

        }

        ?>`

`$menuItem->alias` -> gets the alias of the current item that is being viewed.

Comment: hi @f00bar , I have edited my post. please check.

Comment: okay then you have to code some ajax call targeting this php script ... then this server side script should return a JSON object containing an array of all links with their alias so you can replace the originals links inside the menu .. `;)`

Comment: yes.. I did some ajax call.. Thanks..

Comment: by the way? how can I tag my ticket as ANSWERED or SOLVED ?

Answer (score 0):

add this jQuery script....

```
$("#firstcat").attr("href","/my_website/index.php/shop?16");
$("#secondcat").attr("href","/my_website/index.php/shop?17");
$("#thirdcat").attr("href","/my_website/index.php/shop?18");
```

Comment: Hi, I have already done this.. but I just thought that what if my client adds another child menu and he doesn't know how to code. So I wanna do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `array` of `{category_id:"someValue", category_alias:"someValue"}` `myArr` in your JS (maybe you can get this with an ajax call, however you do it)

do something like

```
var length = myArr.length;
for(var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
    $("#" + myArr[i].category_alias).attr("href","/my_website/index.php/shop?" + myArr[i].category_id);
}
```

I did not have time to test this though so please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: hi, i have my array in a php, how can I pass this to js ?

Comment: Can't you directly echo the values into the page?

Answer (score 0):

wew! Sorry for the disturbance guys.. But I have to do ajax call to make it work.

I do it like this.

My PHP:
`$q = $_GET['q'];`
`$db = & JFactory::getDBO();`
`$db->setQuery('SELECT id FROM #__k2_categories WHERE alias="' . $q . '"');`
`$result = $db->loadResult();`
`if (!empty($result)) {`
`echo $result;`
`exit();`
`}`

My Script:
`<script type="text/javascript">`
            `(function($){`
                `$(document).ready(function() {`
                    `$('.level2').click(function(e) {`
                        `CurrElId = jQuery(this).attr("id");`
                        `$.ajax({`
                            `type: 'GET',`
                            `url: location.href,`
                            `data: 'q='+CurrElId,`
                            `success: function(data) {`
                                `var basepath = "/mywebsite/index.php/shop";`
                                `location.href = basepath+'?'+data;`
                            `}`
                        `});`
                        `e.preventDefault();`
                    `});`
                `});`
            `})(jQuery);`
        `</script>`

Comment: This might work but this is A LOT of work. Imagine making an ajax call EVERY click of the links. You might want to recode to query all at once, THEN render as href.

Comment: Recode? I find it hard because this is joomla CMS. It takes time to dig joomla core.